# How to put page number with the total number of pages in the right top corner?

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

Specifically, how to put on the top right corner "Page {number} of {number of pages}". Example: Page 1 of 5.

Comment: See the lastpage package.  The top-right corner (as opposed to the header area) can be reached using `\AddToHooks{shipout/background}{...}`/

Answer (score 2):

use `lastpage` and `fancyhdr` package, and you need to compile twice. as follow:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage\space of \pageref{LastPage}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]